# Express routes working locally but not on production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, express, static

We're currently deploying a static react app serve by a nodejs / express server through apache2 reverse proxy. The app index is working fine but i try to redirect if a page don't exist, that's work on localhost but not on the remote server. If i go to `myip/foo`, i receive a
`cannot GET /foo`

here's my server.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("./src/models/db.models");
const compression = require("compression");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
//Disable x-powered-by header for security reason
app.disable("x-powered-by");
// use compression (gzip etc) for each request to increase perf
app.use(compression());
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/index.html");
});
app.get("/signUp/:id", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/index.html");
});
// force: true will drop the table if it already exists (so drop all the data too)
db.sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Server Running ‍(*-*)");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("Error ¯_(ツ)_/¯", err));
require("./src/routes/user.routes")(app);
require("./src/routes/auth.routes")(app);
require("./src/routes/pageContents.routes")(app);
require("./src/routes/survey.routes")(app);
require("./src/routes/theme.routes")(app);
require("./src/routes/question.routes")(app);
require("./src/routes/surveyQuestion.routes")(app);
require("./src/routes/surveyHasUser.routes")(app);
require("./src/routes/answer.routes")(app);
require("./src/routes/surveyHasTheme.routes")(app);
// use static folder to render builded front react app
app.use(express.static("client"));
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

here's my app.js ( frontend ), built and set in the backend folder

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './pages/login/Login.page';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Intro from './pages/questionnaire/Intro/Intro.page';
import Edito from './pages/edito/Edito.page';
import Cgu from './pages/cgu/Cgu.page';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Questionnaire from './pages/questionnaire/Questionnaire/Questionnaire.page';
import Remerciement from './pages/questionnaire/Remerciement/Remerciement.page';
import ListeQuestionnaire from './pages/liste/ListeQuestionnaire.page';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/utils/ProtectedRoute.component';
import AuthService from '../src/services/auth.service';
import LogOut from './components/utils/logOut.component';
import TableauDeBord from './pages/tableauDeBord/tableauDeBord.page';
import SignUp from '../src/pages/signUp/signUp.page';
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/intro" component={Intro} />
                    <Route path="/signUp/:token" component={SignUp} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={() => (AuthService.isAuthenticated() ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Login />)} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/questionnaire" component={Questionnaire} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/remerciement" component={Remerciement} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/listeQuestionnaire" component={ListeQuestionnaire} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/cgu" component={Cgu} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/logOut" component={LogOut} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/edito" component={Edito} />
                    <Route path="/:token" component={SignUp} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/" component={TableauDeBord} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

and finally here's my apache config file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerName domain.com
#    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/html/360-nodejs"
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2errorcustom.log" common

    <Proxy *>
            #Require all granted
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache log's says there is a shutdown when we call `/:id` or `/signUp/:id`, but the server's still running

I can go to direct link to another routes but if i refresh the page i get a 404, if i write it in the URL that doesn't work anymore, 404, and so i cannot query a direct URL like /:id cuz i get a 404 too

Answer (score -1):

Well, as usual, i should better RTFD.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

If you use routers that use the HTML5 pushState history API under the hood (for example, React Router with browserHistory), many static file servers will fail. For example, if you used React Router with a route for /todos/42, the development server will respond to localhost:3000/todos/42 properly, but an Express serving a production build as above will not.

This is because when there is a fresh page load for a /todos/42, the server looks for the file build/todos/42 and does not find it. The server needs to be configured to respond to a request to /todos/42 by serving index.html. For example, we can amend our Express example above to serve index.html for any unknown paths:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
-app.get('/', function (req, res) {
+app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });
```

If you’re using Apache HTTP Server, you need to create a .htaccess file in the public folder that looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

It will get copied to the build folder when you run npm run build.

i modified my server.js and added a .htaccess, things solved.